# Java JButton mouse over color

Tags: java, swing, uimanager

I have a Java Swing application that's using "system" look and feel (as i'm using Windows, i'm getting "native Windows" controls in my app). Now, for "branding" reasons i'm trying to enforce particular color on my buttons but i have a problem. I prefer using UIManager but i can't find any property that would let me choose "button mouse over" color.
Take a look at the picture attached please:

[image]

Seems like i'm stuck with default Windows "light-blue" color for button mouse over (pointer is not visible in this screenshot).

How can i change that color?

For me only option is some sort of UIManager global variable, i simply can't afford to go through all buttons in my app and override some custom button or add listeners for "mouse enter" and "mouse exit".

Comment: Create your custom extension for WindowsButtonUI and override paint method to paint your custom background. Then you can register your UI class. For example: `UIManager.put("ButtonUI", MyWinButtonUI.class.getName())`.

Comment: Had no idea about that! I'll try it!

Comment: Nope, seems like i has no effect. If i put wrong class name buttons are not even painted, which is ok, but if i override WindowsButtonUI and set, for example, different "focusColor" it's not working.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do it is to customize the LAF of your application, using this library [TinyLAF](http://www.muntjak.de/hans/java/tinylaf/index.html).
Very easy to use, with nice control panel to help do some theming and using the created theme file on your project.

Here is a small tutorial on how to use it in case the doc is not too clear
http://yourjavacode.blogspot.com.ng/2013/05/tinylaf-change-your-java-look-and-feel.html

I hope this helped out.

Comment: Upvote as i had no idea about TinyLAF. You don't think this could be changed via UIManager?

Comment: it can @guest86 , like so  UIManager.setLookAndFeel("de.muntjak.tinylookandfeel.TinyLookAndFeel");
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);

check out the small tutorial, is just you placing the default theme on your application root directory